# Azure Data Factory failures

Tags: azure-data-factory

We've started using Azure Data Factories for moving data around between a main system and some reporting systems we're developing.

We've got a few different loaders scheduled and they're running fine almost all of the time but we've had few isolated errors happening.

1. just had  "InternalServerError executing request"
2. "Operation on target RatedSessionsViewDataFlow failed: Hit unexpected failure while allocating compute resources, please retry. If the problem persists, please contact Azure Support"
3. "Operation on target  failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: Unable to retrieve column metadata.","Details":"shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to retrieve column metadata.\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.getDestinationMetadata(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1751)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1646)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:620)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions.com$microsoft$azure$sqldb$spark$DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions$$bulkCopy(DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions.scala:127)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions.scala:54)\n\tat com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameBulkCopyFunctions.scala:52)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:987)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach"}"

each time the pipeline ran through successfully the next time it ran but I hate having failures I don't understand, I've done a fair amount of googling but haven't been able to find any solid leads.
I suspect that 1) is pretty much unknowable but does anybody have any idea about what's happened for 2) or 3) and whether there's anything we can do to reduce the chances of future incidents like them?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see InternalServerError failures occasionally, and a retry almost always works, so I usually add a retry to the DataFlow.